# Subversion remote access

Tags: apache, svn, http

How to enable access to my local svn server (access with http protocol), from my web site with a transparent redirection?

I tried with .htaccess file but I have an http internal error (500)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule http://svnserver.mydomain.com/ https://localip/repoFolder [P]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what you want. For example, can users right now access your repository via `https://localip/repoFolder`? Does DNS know to map `svnserver.mydomain.com` to `localip`? Do you use DHCP which means that `localip` will change from time to time. And, why is one `https` vs. `http`? I'm not an Apache httpd expert, but I think that might be an issue since you have to issue a certificate from one system to another.

Comment: Same questions as above as it looks like you rather need a DNS that a redirection, eg "linking" the public domain name with your local server.

Comment: for users of my svn server since they can access from lan via a local IP address and also from my fixed public IP address via NAT. But my need I want my public address is transparent so I can have a memorable url via a subdomain of my website.